# Traveling to US from Canada what Covid test should I do?

Tags: canada, covid-19

I will be travelling to Canada and from there to US. The US regulations require a negative Covid test and I am currently researching options to do a test. The Hotel I will be staying in recommended a place ([Amani Travel Health Clinic](https://squareup.com/appointments/book/y740no6bmp5e0t/LQ17WN05487T6/services)
) but I do not understand the difference between the different options and they also look a bit pricey. So a couple of questions:

- Can someone recommend what is the best option for a test - it does not have to be the same place but what would a Canadian typically take to travel to US.
- Do the prices listed in this place sounds reasonable?

EDIT: I will be staying in Vancouver the last few days and I will be flying to US

Comment: Where and how long are you staying in Canada? How are you going to the U.S.? In any case $129 for an antigen test is a rip off. There are plenty of providers for antigen test unless your need is particular or urgent. Ask the local pharmacies.

Comment: I will be staying in Vancouver the last couple of days and I am flying to NY

Comment: You can just do the free government COVID test and fly with that

Comment: @JonathanReez could you please elaborate? I don't know what is "the government COVID test".

Comment: Not adding an answer as I don’t know the details but a friend of mine just got the free Covid test from a pharmacy or something like that and used that to fly. It’s whatever is the official free test for Canadians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$129 for a supervised rapid antigen test is definitely overpriced.

I went to Shopper's Drug Mart, a national chain; [here's a list of stores for a randomly chosen Vancouver postal code](https://www1.shoppersdrugmart.ca/en/store-locator?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclsrc=ds&gclsrc=aw.ds), but you could look for stores near your hotel.  You can book a supervised [rapid antigen test](https://www1.shoppersdrugmart.ca/en/health-and-pharmacy/covid-19/testing/antigen-screening), it costs $40 (plus tax) and takes 15-20 minutes (you might want to allow 30 minutes). They gave me a printout of the result; I took a photo with my phone and uploaded it to the airline's check-in page (and brought the paper with me).

Ref: I got a test at SDM in Ontario for travel to Boston last week.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Is this printout considered legal evidence on the US border?

Comment: Yes, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The testing requirements for a non-US-citizen flying to the US are on [this CDC page](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/testing-international-air-travelers.html#anchor_1635127081). A rapid antigen test is acceptable.

Googling "rapid antigen test Vancouver BC" will return many results.

Comment: Yes, I have read the regulations. My question is more on the - are there better options for a place to do the test? Is the price listed on this site reasonable or too expensive?

Comment: Questions about shopping are off-topic here. You should look at the listings, compare prices and locations, and consider how you'd get there to take the test...and then pick one.